# Customized search with application in windows start menu

Tags: c#, windows, search, windows-7

If I search *"chrome facebook.com"* in the Windows7 start menu, it finds a program, so when I press enter it opens chrome and chrome knows that it should open facebook.com in a new tab. I'd like to do the same thing with my application. I use C# with Visual Studio.

[image: Searching in Windows7 start menu]

Comment: As far as I know (an i was able to test this real quick on my computer) you can add arguments to any executable found with this Windows 7+ search function. So `cmd.exe some_command` will work as well as `firefox google.com` and `your_programm some_argument`. You only have to get the commandline arguments within your program and let them do their thang.\

Comment: It works with some executables, but not all. For example Internet Explorer or Skype cannot handle this.

Comment: Ok fine. Those are exceptions (they cannot deal with arguments anyways). But **in general** it works with *any* **program**. Here are some question worth answering before going on: Is your program located on a path that is accessible by the windows search indexer? If yes, does your program accept commandline arguments? If yes, have you refreshed your search index? If yes, have you attemted to "custom search" your program?

Comment: Yes, my program is probably accessible. If I search for it (test.exe) it shows up as a Program, not as a Document. I retrieve arguments when the program runs with _Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()_. If I type in the full path of the test.exe and type arguments next to it there are no search results but it opens up anyway and it works fine, but simply searching _test.exe something_ opens up a search window with no results. What do you mean custom search my program?

Comment: Well essentially, what you did '$your_program $your_custom_search_string'. This is a bit of a mystery. I have added my Project folder to the search parameters of my Windows Search Indexer and the aforementioned method works on almost, but not every program. This beaivor seems a bit random, I admit. I'm gonna have to search for any information on this myself.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So far I figured out that it's not connected to the lnk files, because if you search for chrome, you get the result Google Chrome, but if you type _chrome www.something.._ then it's not _Google Chrome_ anymore, just simply _Chrome_. If you type _Google Chrome something_ it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Key in the registry called `App Path` where you can define the path to a Program. This will be checked by the Windows Search Box and it allows you to pass arguments to said Program.

It is located at:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`

So all you need to do for your Program `TestProgram.exe` is to add a Key to `App Paths` called `TestProgram.exe` with the value being it's Path in the FileSystem. It may be nescessery to add a string value called `Path` containing the path aswell.

Then when searching for `TestProgram[.exe]` you can append arguments.